# about event.Skip()

Tags: wxpython

I want to invoke `OnstaticDown`, and use `event.Skip()` to invoke it's parent widget `onPanelDown`.

But only `OnstaticDown` is invoked, and I don't understand why. Why isn't `static`s parent panel receiving the event?

My code:

```
 self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.onPanelDown)
 self.static = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.NewId(), "First Name",pos=(10, 50),size=(100,100))
 self.static.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnstaticDown)

 def onPanelDown(self,event):
        print 'panel-------------22'
 def OnstaticDown(self,event):
        print 'static============11'
        event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.Skip()` will invoke the controls default handler (ie StaticText). I don't believe static text has a default handler, though, as it's not designed to be interacted with, it's just a label for displaying text.

you could post the event to the panel after dealing with it in static down, `wx.PostEvent(self.panel,event)` or I don't think it'd be bad practice just to pass it `self.onPanelDown(event)` although it wouldn't be as well suited to change.

you could always make a function to pass/post an event to the controls parent

```
def PostToParent(control,event):
    wx.PostEvent(control.GetParent(),event)
```

---

**EDIT:**
That's just not how it works, only some types of events propagate to parent widgets (events in the wx.CommandEvent hierarchy, which mouse events aren't a part of). Try commenting out the binding on the static text, if you click right on it you wont trigger the panels left down, because you're clicking on the static text, not the panel.  `event.Skip()` will just mark the event and allow to to propagate to other bindings after running your handler, if you dont it wont, and nothing more will happen with the event.

The most obvious example of this is if you close a window the frame emits an `EVT_CLOSE` event which wx will pick up and close the window. If you bind a method to `EVT_CLOSE` it will trigger before the underlying wx event handler. If you don't call `event.Skip` the event will never get to the wx handler and the frame wont close when you try to close it, but if you do call `event.Skip` it will get handled by the wx event handler after yours, and close the frame.

`wx.PostEvent` on the other hand is a way to send an event to a specific widget, and have any bindings bound to that specific event, process the event. In this case forwarding on the left down event to the panel has the same effect as clicking on the panel yourself.

Comment: Thank you!." `event.Skip()` will invoke the controls default handler (ie StaticText). " why not continue to invoke it's parent windows(ie panel) `self.onPanelDown`? and what's the relation between `postEvent` and `event.skip()`. thanks for your answer again